# Nested group with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to group a list of items using LINQ for display in a repeater. I have a query that almost does what I need but not quite.

My data looks like

```
Cart object 
{ID: 10, isInventory: True, Pricing: 4},
{ID: 10, isInventory: True, Pricing: 20},
{ID: 10, isInventory: False, Pricing: 5},
{ID: 10, isInventory: False, Pricing: 23},
{ID: 74, isInventory: False, Pricing: 7}
```

And I want to group by isInventory, then group each of those by ID. Currently I have a query that comes close but still not right.

```
var grouped = from cart in shoppingCart.Cart
                      group cart by cart.IsInventoryStorage into Cart1
                      from CartGroup in
                          (from cart in Cart1
                           group cart by cart.BranchID)
                      group CartGroup by CartGroup.Key;
```

It looks like it is grouped correctly, but the `Keys` on isInventory, and I'd ideally want it to be `key.isInventory` then each of those groups be sorted by `key.ID`.

Thanks

Comment: If I've understood you correctly, you don't mean group by by order by. Then a subsequent ordering needs to use ThenBy, or it'll destroy the first ordering.

Comment: If you follow the [How to: Create a Nested Group (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545974.aspx) you'll notice that the syntax is a bit weird, but anyway, in your case the `group CartGroup by CartGroup.Key` should be `group CartGroup by Cart1.Key`

Comment: Ivan you've caught my mistake, that is exactly what the problem is. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `orderby` in query syntax.  Note that subsequent ordering conditions are separated via a comma.

```
void Main()
{
    var cart = new List<Cart>();

    cart.Add(new Cart { ID = 10, isInventory = true, Pricing = 4 });
    cart.Add(new Cart { ID = 10, isInventory = true, Pricing = 20});
    cart.Add(new Cart { ID = 10, isInventory = false, Pricing = 5});
    cart.Add(new Cart { ID = 10, isInventory = false, Pricing = 23});
    cart.Add(new Cart { ID = 74, isInventory = false, Pricing = 7});

    var grouped = from c in cart
                  orderby c.isInventory, c.ID
                  select c;

    grouped.Dump();
}

public class Cart
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool isInventory { get; set; }
    public int Pricing { get; set; }

}
```

This outputs the data as such:

```
10 False 5 
74 False 7 
10 False 23 
10 True 4 
10 True 20
```

Comment: This groups the items in a list, but not grouped by Key as in above answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cart=new []{
    new {ID= 10, isInventory= true, Pricing= 4},
    new {ID= 10, isInventory= true, Pricing= 20},
    new {ID= 10, isInventory= false, Pricing= 5},
    new {ID= 10, isInventory= false, Pricing= 23},
    new {ID= 74, isInventory= false, Pricing= 7}
};

var results=cart.GroupBy(c=>c.isInventory)
    .SelectMany(grp1=>grp1.GroupBy(th=>th.ID),(grp1,grp2)=>new {grp1=grp1,grp2=grp2})
    .GroupBy(temp0=>temp0.grp1.Key,temp0=>temp0.grp2)
    .Dump();
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: What did you use to visualise the result?